# nodemon isn't running in vs code terminal

Tags: node.js, express, npm, nodemon

```
PS D:\my-express-server> npm i nodemon

added 32 packages, and audited 90 packages in 6s

10 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
PS D:\my-express-server> nodemon -v
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,        
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon -v
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

PS D:\my-express-server> nodemon .\server.js
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,        
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon .\server.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

I want to run fully nodemon in vs code so please give me solution for it.

Comment: Either install it globally using `npm i --global nodemon` or add this command to `package.json` as a script

Answer (score 1):

The solution is straightforward...

first, avoid using the '.' for locating the directory, it's './' or else you can just write the entry file name as it is.

And also, you would have to write npx in the beginning.

Like in your scenario, you can simply do this:

```bash
npx nodemon server.js
```

Comment: why npx as prefix??

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `nodemon` in your project directory every time if you haven't installed it globally. Use `npm install nodemon -g`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For use in local you should use this statement:

```bash
npx nodemon name
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `nodemon -v` from your terminal it tries to resolve it as a shell command as `nodemon` is not installed globally. To do that run:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Running `npm install` (or `npm i`) without `-g` installs packages in the local directory of your project, which means that `nodemon` is inside your project's `node_modules`, to use that local installation, add `nodemon` as one of your scripts in package.json, for example:

```
{
  "name": "sof-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon"
```

And then run it with `npm run SCRIPT_NAME`, and as in my example: `npm run start:dev`.

Also, since `nodemon` is a dependency that you "may/should" only use on the development/local environment, you should install it as a devDepdency with `-D` or `--save-dev` flags:

```
npm i -D nodemon
```

Would add it to `devDependencies`

```
{
  "name": "sof-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

And to run my dev server with `nodemon` I would execute:

```
npm run start:dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed nodemon dependency globaly and none of the above commands works in order to run your main node.js project file (node app.js or node server.js). Try to run you project using "npm start".

Answer (score 0):

hi see the below link for solve your nodemon dont start in vs code
in brief

steps:

1. powershell
2. get-executionpolicy
3. set-executionpolicy unrestricted
4. hit y

you can also see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MBPDG6XDfE&ab_channel=TechnoED)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, nodemon not work for execution policy.

To fix it, open PowerShell and set to Restricted, which prevents running scripts.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

And press - Y. Then-

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

And press - Y.

If you want check - `Get-ExecutionPolicy` and you see the result is- `Unrestricted`.